# Scripting environment setup in windows

Tags: windows, scripting, windows-7, batch-file

When I start my day programming (using windows 7), I have a bunch of windows I'd like open and ready:

- command prompt in my code directory running the DevNull smtp java server
- command prompt in the tomcat\bin directory with startup.bat running after rmdir /S /Q'ing work and test webapp directories
- IntelliJ running
- after tomcat loads (fine with just having a timer), Firefox with my webapp loaded
- after tomcat loads, Chrome with my webapp loaded

Those are pretty core...  then it depends on what exactly I'm working on as far as other apps I need open.

So how do I write a script I can double click on and have all the above ready for me, saving me a couple minutes each day and a little less annoying getting started?  I know about .bat files, is it easy to do the above with a .bat file?  Is there a nice app that can easily do the above for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty straight-forward to put all of that in a bat file, something like this:

```
@echo off

rmdir /S /Q testdir
rmdir /S /Q workdir

start cmd /K c:\foo\bar.bat
start cmd /K c:\foo\bas.bat

start firefox.exe "http://www.stackoverflow.com/"
```

Comment: very nice, thanks.  start firefox.exe works the same for chrome.exe.  I just need to find the executable filename for intellij I guess.  The only remaining question is how do I start firefox/chrome after tomcat has fully loaded?  Is there a way to tell?  Is there a sleep function?

Comment: As Slaks suggested, there is a `sleep` command in the resource kit. An sort-of-hack approach is to use the `ping` command, running `ping -n 10 127.0.0.1` will cause approx. 10 seconds delay.

Comment: No, it will cause a nine-second delay.

Comment: Joey: Correct, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all that into a batch file, and use the `sleep` command from the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools.

Comment: I have to get a toolkit to sleep?  there isn't something simpler/smaller I can quickly download?